# Multiply in jQuery, but one number is from rangeslider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in calculating a live changing number; I cannot multiply two numbers. One is live (changing with slider, see second script) so I need to multiply the numbers.

```html
<script>
$('#customer-worth').on('keyup', function(){
  $('#lafinale-profit').text(($(this).val()*($'#closed-deals-roi-calc'.val()))); //this here is the problem. I dont know how to live update number from other script (closed-deals-roi-calc)
});
</script>

<script>
$('.fs-rangeslider_track').on('touchstart',function(e){
    $('#closed-deals-roi-calc').text(((parseFloat($('#number-from- 
       slider').innerText)/100*8.7)).toFixed(1));
</script>
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you find a solution with a sample of the html code that you're updating

Comment: I think part of the problem might be that you're not actually reading the closed-deals-roi-calc element `$(this).val() * $("#closed-deals-roi-calc").val()` might work

Comment: What do you mean by not reading ? can i give you Anydesk id so you can Join and see the script , it is in the Webflow, thats why cant share link

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require, add an `input` event handler to both the text and the range slider. This event handler is what performs the calculation from the values in those controls and updates the required element in the DOM, something like this:

```js
let updateUi = () => $('#lafinale-profit').text(($('#customer-worth').val() * $('#closed-deals-roi-calc').val()) || 0);

$('#customer-worth, #closed-deals-roi-calc').on('input', updateUi);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Customer worth: <input type="number" id="customer-worth" value="1" />
ROI calc: <input type="range" min="1" max="10" id="closed-deals-roi-calc" value="5" />

<div id="lafinale-profit"></div>
```